# Deprecated: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future

Tags: php

I have this error appear in php 7.3

> Deprecated: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior

The line is :

```
if ($this->Category->getPath() && strpos('_', $this->Category->getPath())) {
```

It seems it come from this code : `strpos('_', $this->Category->getPath()`

`$this->Category->getPath()` can return this value for example :

```
int(8)  
string(3) "8_9"
```

Comment: The error message is clear, the second parameter for strpos must be a string. Your method can return integers. That is no longer allowed. Solution: cast the result to a string.

Comment: @JohnConde ok, tk found the solution : strpos('_', (string)$this->Category->getPath())

Comment: Convert the integer into string

Comment: @u_mulder the question is how to prevent this error, isn't it?

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me

```
$suffix = strval($this->config->item('controller_suffix'));
$pos = !empty($suffix) ? strpos($class, $suffix) : FALSE;
if ($pos === FALSE)
{
    $class .= $suffix;
}
parent::set_class($class);
```

Comment: Looks like InvoicePlane on PHP7, am I right? This Router.php file is part of the framework that InvoicePlane uses, was it CodeIgniter?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is also working for php 7.4 with codeigniter HMVC structure.

Answer (score 17):

All you have to do is pass in a string as the parameter for [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
strpos('_', strval($this->Category->getPath()))
```

Or, ensure the `Category->getPath()` returns a string and not a mixed type.

Comment: Thanks. It fulfilled the need.

Answer (score 5):

`if (strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)`
replace with
`if ($suffix && strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)`

Here you can see Details

https://github.com/raknjak/CIMembership/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to fix

```
public function set_class($class)
{
    $suffix = $this->config->item('controller_suffix');
    if ($suffix && strpos($class, $suffix) === FALSE)
    {
        $class .= $suffix;
    }
    parent::set_class($class);
}
```